# Significant difference in the same variable - between groups

Tags: repeated-measures, nonparametric

Good morning,
I have two groups of participants, and the same variable, measured in three different moments (categorical data- non-parametric test, between groups).
I would like to know which test should I use, to know the significant difference in this variable.
Thank you

Comment: Hi! see my answer to a simial question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/593902/56940)